# Is there any TF implementation of the Original BERT other than Google and HuggingFace?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

Trying to find any `Tensorflow/Keras` implementation of the `original BERT model trained using MLM/NSP`. The official google and HuggingFace implementations are very complex and has so much of added functionalities. But I want to learn and implement `BERT` for just learning its working.

Any leads will be helpful?

Comment: Something like [this](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/masked_language_modeling/)?

Comment: @M.Innat this is exactly that. Thanks. Can you please provide the link as the answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can try the following implementation of [MLP-BERT](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/masked_language_modeling/) TensorFlow. It's a simplified version and easy to follow comparatively.